# measure the size and the smoothness of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis

In a book, a sentence is going on:

"Function spaces are tools with which to describe the size and the smoothness of functions. For example, $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ measures the size."

The expression of the "measure of smoothness" makes sense, albeit a bit. For example, the degree of derivation. I don't know if my example is correct.

But the expression of "measure of size" did not mean anything to me. Can you explain it? What does it mean "$L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ measures the size"?

Comment: Belonging to $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ does restrict the size $|f(x)|$ of the values. Since $f$ can be quite irregular (e.g., it can be very big on very small sets) a precise meaning is not so obvious (like, e.g., in the case of $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$). For $q\in (1,\infty)$ a nice application of Fubini's theorem  gives $$\|f\|_q^q=\frac{1}{q-1}\int_0^\infty t^{q-1} \lambda^n(\{|f|\ge t\}) dt$$ which means that the decreasing function $\lambda_n(|f|\ge t)$ has to converge to $0$ with a certain speed.

Comment: @Jochen can you give an example of a function that can be very big on very small sets and its relation to class $L^q$. Also, can you explain the claim "... has to converge to $0$ with a certain speed"? Thank you very much.

Comment: For $n=1$, you can imagine a continuous function with very high but narrow peaks at the integers which might be in $L^q$. To get a feeling concerning the remark about the speed, you might check for which $\alpha$ an estimate $\lambda^n(\|f\|\ge t) \le t^\alpha$ (for big $t$) would be enough to ensure the finiteness of the integral.